# Rsyslog messages not making it to local logfile

Tags: centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I've been tasked with setting up longer/better log retention for our postgres servers, but after configuring postgres to ship logs to syslog via `local0` I've found that they never actually hit the configured local file.

**`/etc/rsyslog.d/postgresql.conf`:**

```
local0.* /company/data/psql/company_cluster/log/postgresql.log
```

Relevant postgres config:

```
log_destination = 'syslog'
syslog_facility = 'local0'
```

Once I got the config in place and reloaded/restarted services I noticed that while nothing was going into the specified log file [even after `touch`ing it] I *was* seeing messages piped into graylog which has a `*.*` rule.

Even stranger is that `logger -p local0.info test` or any other facility doesn't generate a message anywhere that I can find. Same goes for any other `local` facility, or even `mail.none`.

Rsyslog seems to be restarting cleanly, I've doubled-checked the selinux context on the config file, and I can't find any relevant info logged from rsyslog itself. What's happening?

All rsyslog config:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/* | grep -v -e '^\s*#' -e '^\s*$'
$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imjournal
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging on
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

# graylog.conf
*.* @graylogmaster.rancher.company.ca:8514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
# listen.conf
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
# postgresql.conf
local0.* /company/data/psql/company_cluster/log/postgresql.log
```

---

**Edit:** "Not Really A Solution" Solution

Something seems to be wrong with Rsyslog [and maybe more] on the particular server that I was working on when I originally posted this question. Restarting the service hasn't done anything and I'm waiting for a maintenance window to either restart or reprovision this server.

This same config works just fine on other servers, but with the caveat that `LOCAL0` seems to be invalid in at least some contexts, but `local0` works everywhere.